# Ignore files less than 200KB in Azure Data Factory Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

There are empty  files being dropped into sftp location causing my pipelines to fail as there are no column headers.

is there a way to filter out files less than 200kb in Azure Data Factory SFTP source connection?

Or is there a better way to handle empty files in ADF.

[Pipeline Configuration Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYIuT.png)

Comment: Hi @VSU, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to filter out files less than 200kb in Azure Data Factory SFTP source connection?

Yes, these is. You need combine [Get Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) + [For each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) + [If condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity) actives to achieve your request:

1. Get Metadata 1 to get all the file lists.
2. For each the files.
3. Inner For each active, Get Metadata 2 to get the file size.
   Then add an If Condition to filter the file which size <200 K: `@greater(activity('Get file size').output.size,20)`.

The pipeline overview:
[image]

ForEach inner actives:

[image]

Note:

1. Get file size active need a dataset parameter to set the ForEach item as filename.
2. Get file list and size are using different source but with same
   path.

If you have any other concerns ,please feel free to let me know.

HTH.

Comment: What do you mean with "2. [...] different source but with same path.". A different data set?